# Add List Box (On Click) in Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla, styles, box

I want to create a list box, as depicted below, in Joomla 3.x but I don't know what should I do or like similar.

[image]

who can suggest to me for solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste  following code for your php file

```
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen');
```

Create a List box

```
 <?php
$options = array();
$options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', '', '- please select -');
$options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', 'Office spaces', 'Office spaces');
$options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', 'Residents', 'Residents');

echo JHTMLSelect::genericlist($options, 'category', 'class="selectbox"', 'value', 'text', $row->category);
?>
```

Comment: What is `$row->category`?

Comment: Which is selected or active elemet